# batch insert text while keeping numbers

Tags: batch-file

I have a code to get me the results by using Stephans for loop thank you but I am still having problems explained below

original text:

```
bbox 7 25 6 04
```

new text:

```
first.one 7
second.two 25
third.three 6
fourth.four 04
```

below is a code i used to try to capture lines with bbox then miss them out (just as a test) but it always shows them if I can get this to work I will also need a code to return the complete line (unmodified) if bbox is false.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-20" %%a in (input.txt) do (
echo findstr "bbox" "%%a"
if errorlevel=1 (
echo. >> output.txt
) else (
echo %%a >> output.txt
))
pause
```

Comment: What is the pattern you want to search for? and could you provide a sample of the file content being searched? instead of just the matched line.

Comment: "request" is wrong. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: show us the batch file, you need help with. What does it do and how does that differ to what it should do?

Comment: start with this command: `for /f "tokens=2-5" %a in ("bbox 7 25 6 04") do @echo %a,%b,%c,%d` (Note; this is command line syntax. If you use it in a batch file, double each `%`: `%%a` etc.)

Comment: I don't think that will work bbox is generic but the 4 numbers after are different on each bbox and they can be single or double numbers 7 25 6 04 were just used for the example.

Comment: @malik, I asked for a sample of the file content yesterday in order to determine how best to formulate a regular expression pattern for the string match. I would appreciate it were you to find time to do so. In the meantime try entering, `FindStr/?` at the Command prompt, put your feet up and take a read.

Comment: sorry compo here is a sample file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/o9xv88cwikx57a2/asuka.txt and thanks  Stephan this way will work I just need to find a any line with a bbox and return the full line for modifying I am reading up now and hope to have a code up soon (looking forward to making my first batch code)

Comment: I have posted the code I wrote but it is not working as it should be.

Comment: There are 39 `bbox` lines. Some of them have dupes. Do you need a specific line? To get all the numbers: `for /f "tokens=2-5" %a in ('find "bbox" asuka.txt') do @echo %a,%b,%c,%d` If you need a specific line, tell us, how to find it.

Comment: ok so the orginal text file needs to be copied exactly the same as the original but any line that have bbox need to be reformatted from bbox #1 #2 #3 #4 to 4 new lines text.text #1 (new line) text.text #2 (new line) text.text #3 (new line) text.text #4  .just checking is there any way to check what line of the text file your are working in the for loop ?

Answer (score 0):

a `for /f` loop typically ignores empty lines. So we have to be sure, there are no empty lines (`find /n /v "" file.txt` prepends the line number to each line)
The rest is quite straight:

```
@echo off
(
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%x in ('find /n /v "" asuka.txt') do (
  title woking on line nr %%x
  for /f "tokens=1-6,*" %%a in ("@ %%y") do (
    if "%%b"=="bbox" (
      echo  first.one   %%c
      echo  second.two  %%d
      echo  third.three %%e
      echo  fourth.four %%f
      REM lines above: between 'echo' and text, there are a space and a TAB
      REM lines above: and a TAB between text and '%%?' 
    ) else echo/%%y
  )
))>asuka.new
```

Comment: thanks for the help and but this code just made a exact copy of the original file with all bboxes in their original format.

Comment: tried a nested for loop with a counter so the same line is copied but it did not work    @echo off
    set line=0
    (for /f "tokens=1-15" %%b in (input.txt) do (
    set line+=1
    if "%%b"=="bbox" (
    echo %%b
    ) else (
    set cline=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (input.txt) do (
    set cline+=1
    if "%line%"=="%cline%" (
    echo %%a
    )))))> output.txt
    pause

Comment: sorry, had a mixup with the variables. Try edited code please.

Answer (score 0):

I finally cracked it by modifying your code thanks Stephan for all the help. my project was a bit bigger then just the bboxes here is the completed code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set tab=    
(
for /f "tokens=* delims=[]" %%a in (input.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=1-15" %%b in ("%%a") do (

set attack=false
set atknum=0

    if "%%b"=="attack" (
    set attack=true
    set atknum=1
    ) else if "%%b"=="attack2" (
    set attack=true
    set atknum=2
    ) else if "%%b"=="attack3" (
    set attack=true
    set atknum=3
    ) else if "%%b"=="attack4" (
    set attack=true
    set atknum=4
    ) else if "%%b"=="attack5" (
    set attack=true
    set atknum=5
    ) else if "%%b"=="attack6" (
    set attack=true
    set atknum=6
    ) else if "%%b"=="attack7" (
    set attack=true
    set atknum=7
    ) else if "%%b"=="attack8" (
    set attack=true
    set atknum=8
    ) else if "%%b"=="attack9" (
    set attack=true
    set atknum=9
    )

    if "%%b"=="bbox" (
    echo %tab% bbox.position.x %%c
    echo %tab% bbox.position.y %%d
    echo %tab% bbox.size.x %%e
    echo %tab% bbox.size.y %%f
    ) else if "!attack!"=="true" (
    if "%%e"=="0" (
        echo %tab% attack.damage.type !atknum!
        echo %tab% attack.size.x 0
        ) else (
    echo %tab% attack.damage.type !atknum!
    echo %tab% attack.position.x %%c
    echo %tab% attack.position.y %%d
    echo %tab% attack.size.x %%e
    echo %tab% attack.size.y %%f
    echo %tab% attack.damage.force %%g
    echo %tab% attack.reaction.fall.force %%h
    echo %tab% attack.block.penetrate %%i
    echo %tab% attack.effect.hit.flash.disable %%j
    echo %tab% attack.reaction.pause.time %%k
    echo %tab% attack.reaction.fall.velocity.y 2
    echo %tab% attack.reaction.fall.velocity.x 2
            )
    ) else if "%%b"=="hitflash" (
    echo %tab% attack.effect.hit.flash.model %%c
    ) else if "%%b"=="hitfx" (
    echo %tab% attack.effect.hit.flash.sound %%c
    ) else if "%%b"=="damageonlanding" (
    echo %tab% attack.damage.land.force %%c
    echo %tab% attack.damage.land.mode %%d
    ) else if "%%b"=="dropv" (
    echo %tab% attack.reaction.fall.velocity.y %%c
    echo %tab% attack.reaction.fall.velocity.x %%d
    ) else if "%%b"=="anim" (
    echo.
    echo %%a
    ) else  echo %%a
    ))) >output.txt
```

Comment: I really wanted to support drag and drop but whenever i use %1 , %~1 or %* for the first loops input file all i get in output.txt if the location to the file i just dropped and nothing else can anyone help with this please.